# error: line 8 parsing error unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

unexpected token

I don't know where the error.
I just followed the book.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';


class App extends Component 
{
return(
    <div>
        <HelloWorld />
        <HelloWorld />
        <HelloWorld />
    </div>
);
};
```

I want to know why this could be an error.

Comment: I formatted your code (by putting 4 spaces at the start of every line btw) - just double check now that what you see here is exactly what you see in your editor?

Comment: Every class component should have a `render` method. You have forgotten to define one. Just add the render method and return your view from this function.

Comment: Question is still open, could you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Using `React.Component`, you need to define a **render** method to return your DOM. You can find more details on [React.Component documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

You might have confused some examples with the new shiny syntax, [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), which now use a `function object` instead of a `class object` :

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```